# Query that groups, buy gives oldest ID not newest

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL database where I am running a query that returns a group of records, grouped by UNIT_ID.

Raw data:

```
ID, UNIT_ID, BILL_TYPE, ADDED_ON
 3, 1130,     1,       '2014-01-01'
 4, 1130,     1,       '2014-02-01'
 5, 1130,     1,       '2014-03-01'
 6, 1234,     1,       '2014-01-02'
 7, 1234,     1,       '2014-02-02'
```

If I run my current query:

```
select * 
  from bills 
 where bill_type = 1 
 group 
    by unit_id 
 order 
    by unit_id
     , added_on desc;
```

... I get:

```
3, 1130, 1, '2014-01-01'
6, 1234, 1, '2014-01-02'
```

.. but I want:

```
5, 1130, 1, '2014-03-01'
7, 1234, 1, '2014-02-02'
```

Basically, I want the newest entries (highest ADDED_ON for each UNIT_ID, not the oldest. How can I get this?

Thanks, Bob

Comment: `select * from bills where bill_type = 1 group by unit_id order by added_on, unit_id desc;`

Comment: Gives the exact same output.

Comment: Then order is only by `ID DESC` that will give you the proper result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT bills.id, bills.unit_id, bills.added_on
FROM bills 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT unit_id, MAX(added_on) as added_on
FROM bills
GROUP BY unit_id 
) AS b
ON bills.unit_id = b.unit_id
  AND bills.added_on = b.added_on
WHERE bills.bill_type = 1
```

Comment: Many thanks, works like a charm! Just has to make it MAX(added_on) as added_on, and it was fine.

Comment: oops, sorry, fixed :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the following technique

```
select b.* from bills b
left join bills b1 
on b1.UNIT_ID = b.UNIT_ID
and b1.ID > b.ID
where 
b.BILL_TYPE = 1 
and b1.id is null
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html